# SQL Server How To Return NULL Instead of 0 IF A GROUPED Value Doesn't Have Rows in Source

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Here's a SQL Fiddle with the source data, what I've tried so far, and what I expect to get as output. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/daf90/2

I have a `GameWinnings` table, with rows containing Contestant name, the round he/she played, and the amount won in that round.

I need to produce a report that SUMs up all the winnings per round, by Contestant.

The condition I'm stuck in is that if a Contestant has not played in a particular round, the `RoundWinningsAmount` for that round should be `NULL` not `0`. I think a `CROSS APPLY` or `PIVOT` / `UNPIVOT` might do it, haven't been able to nail it down yet.

Here's the table and initial data, followed by Problem statement and expected output vs what I've tried.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.GameWinnings
(
    Contestant varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    GameRound int NOT NULL,
    RoundWinningsAmount numeric(38, 6) NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.GameWinnings (Contestant,GameRound, RoundWinningsAmount) 
VALUES('Ms Junaiqua',2,33333);
INSERT INTO dbo.GameWinnings (Contestant,GameRound, RoundWinningsAmount) 
VALUES('Mr Wang',1,NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.GameWinnings (Contestant,GameRound, RoundWinningsAmount) 
VALUES('Mr Wang',1,NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.GameWinnings (Contestant,GameRound, RoundWinningsAmount) 
VALUES('Mr Wang',1,100);
INSERT INTO dbo.GameWinnings (Contestant,GameRound, RoundWinningsAmount) 
VALUES('Mr Wang',2,NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.GameWinnings (Contestant,GameRound, RoundWinningsAmount) 
VALUES('Thad Chad ',1,99);
INSERT INTO dbo.GameWinnings (Contestant,GameRound, RoundWinningsAmount) 
VALUES('Thad Chad ',1,1);
INSERT INTO dbo.GameWinnings (Contestant,GameRound, RoundWinningsAmount) 
VALUES('Thad Chad ',1,NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.GameWinnings (Contestant,GameRound, RoundWinningsAmount) 
VALUES('Thad Chad ',2,50);
INSERT INTO dbo.GameWinnings (Contestant,GameRound, RoundWinningsAmount) 
VALUES('Thad Chad ',2,150);
INSERT INTO dbo.GameWinnings (Contestant,GameRound, RoundWinningsAmount) 
VALUES('Thad Chad ',2,NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.GameWinnings (Contestant,GameRound, RoundWinningsAmount) 
VALUES('Thad Chad ',2,NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.GameWinnings (Contestant,GameRound, RoundWinningsAmount) 
VALUES('Thad Chad ',3,300);

CREATE TABLE ExpectedOutput
(
Contestant varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Round_1_Winnings numeric(38, 6) NULL,
Round_2_Winnings numeric(38, 6) NULL,
Round_3_Winnings numeric(38, 6) NULL
); 

-- Expected output
INSERT INTO ExpectedOutput VALUES ('Mr Wang', 100 , 0 , NULL)
INSERT INTO ExpectedOutput VALUES ('Ms Junaiqua', NULL , 33333 , NULL)
INSERT INTO ExpectedOutput VALUES ('Thad Chad', 100 , 200 , 300)
```

IF you do a `SELECT *`, then this is the Data.

[image]

#### Problem Statement & Requirements

There are 3 Rounds in a Game. So GameRound column value will always be only 1 or 2 or 3.

1. Create a resultset by Contestant, that SUMs up each contestants
   winning for each round
2. If a contestant hasn't participated in a
   certain round, the SUM value for that round should be `NULL`, not
   `0`

So in the sample data above

1. **Mr Wang** has played in Round 1 and Round 2, but not in Round 3. So Round 3 `SUM` should be `NULL` not `0`. Round 2 `SUM` should be `0` since he played in Round 2, but didn't win any money.
2. **Ms Junaiqua** has played in Round 2 only, and not in Round 1 or Round 3, so Round 1 and Round 3 `SUM` should be `NULL` not `0`.
3. **Thad Chad** has played in all 3 Rounds, so all 3 Rounds should have the `SUM` value.

#### What I've tried

```
-- Current query I've tried to get desired output.
-- The query is returning 0, instead of NULL for Rounds where Contestant didn't participate.
-- I know that this is happening because I am returning 0 in the ELSE of the CASE.
-- Not sure how to fix it. 
SELECT
    Contestant,
    SUM ( CASE WHEN GameRound = 1 THEN RoundWinningsAmount ELSE 0 END) Round_1_Winnings,
    SUM ( CASE WHEN GameRound = 2 THEN RoundWinningsAmount ELSE 0 END) Round_2_Winnings,
    SUM ( CASE WHEN GameRound = 3 THEN RoundWinningsAmount ELSE 0 END) Round_3_Winnings
FROM dbo.GameWinnings
GROUP BY Contestant
```

#### Expected Output vs Actual Output.

The values in Red need to be the values shown in green.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simple need to change NULL to zero *before* the aggregation.

Standard SQL solution, runnning on every DBMS:

```
SELECT
   Contestant,
   SUM ( CASE WHEN GameRound = 1 THEN COALESCE(RoundWinningsAmount,0) END) AS Round_1_Winnings,
   SUM ( CASE WHEN GameRound = 2 THEN COALESCE(RoundWinningsAmount,0) END) AS Round_2_Winnings,
   SUM ( CASE WHEN GameRound = 3 THEN COALESCE(RoundWinningsAmount,0) END) AS Round_3_Winnings
FROM dbo.GameWinnings
GROUP BY Contestant;
```

Comment: In the end, I'd also come up with something similar, except that I was using `ISNULL` instead of `COALESCE`. I see that this is a much simpler solution and just learned that `COALESCE` is ANSI SQL solution so will work on all RDBMS'.

Answer (score 3):

you can use a **PIVOT** query like below:

<kbd>**[see live demo](http://rextester.com/YPL83144)**</kbd>

```
select * from 
(
    select 
        RoundWinnings=ISNULL(sum(RoundWinningsAmount),0),
        Contestant, 
        GameRound
    from GameWinnings
    group by Contestant, GameRound
)src
pivot
(
    max(RoundWinnings) 
    for GameRound in ([1],[2],[3])
 )p
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT
Contestant,
SUM ( CASE WHEN b.Rounds = 1 THEN isnull(RoundWinningsAmount, 0) END) Round_1_Winnings,
SUM ( CASE WHEN b.Rounds = 2 THEN isnull(RoundWinningsAmount, 0) END) Round_2_Winnings,
SUM ( CASE WHEN b.Rounds = 3 THEN isnull(RoundWinningsAmount, 0) END) Round_3_Winnings
FROM dbo.GameWinnings a
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT DISTINCT GameRound as rounds 
          FROM dbo.GameWinnings
        ) b
ON a.GameRound = b.rounds
GROUP BY Contestant;
```

You create all rounds and left join to those to catch the no shows. An isnull prevents null when participated but not won.

Your [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/daf90/52)

Answer (score 1):

Using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT
  Contestant,
  SUM(CASE WHEN GameRound=1 THEN COALESCE(RoundWinningsAmount,s.p)END) Round1Win,
  SUM(CASE WHEN GameRound=2 THEN COALESCE(RoundWinningsAmount,s.p)END) Round2Win,
  SUM(CASE WHEN GameRound=3 THEN COALESCE(RoundWinningsAmount,s.p)END) Round3Win
FROM dbo.GameWinnings g
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 0 FROM dbo.GameWinnings g2 
             WHERE g.Contestant = g2.Contestant
               AND g.GameRound = g2.GameRound) s(p)
GROUP BY Contestant;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=927f84e13d06b041cc3cf313b9e2b963)**

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of different ways to do this, but I would recommend using a Common Table Expression, and then making changes depending on performance/needs.

```
;WITH Results AS (
    SELECT
    Contestant,
    SUM ( CASE WHEN GameRound = 1 THEN RoundWinningsAmount ELSE 0 END) Round_1_Winnings,
    SUM ( CASE WHEN GameRound = 2 THEN RoundWinningsAmount ELSE 0 END) Round_2_Winnings,
    SUM ( CASE WHEN GameRound = 3 THEN RoundWinningsAmount ELSE 0 END) Round_3_Winnings
    FROM dbo.GameWinnings
    GROUP BY Contestant 
)
SELECT
    Contestant, 
    CASE WHEN Round_1_Winnings = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Round_1_Winnings END
    CASE WHEN Round_2_Winnings = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Round_2_Winnings END
    CASE WHEN Round_3_Winnings = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Round_3_Winnings END
FROM Results;
```

Comment: Not sure if you tried your solution on sqlfiddle, but this also doesn't work. It's giving `NULL` where 0 is expected. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/daf90/8  for your query results. Mr Wang for Round 2 should have `0` not `NULL`

Comment: @shawnt00 I don't have enough cred to comment on your post, but there's an issue when you have one or more positive scores for a round, and a single 0 score.

Comment: @Shiva I thought the expected output was null, and the current output was 0.

Comment: I don't understand. I think simply stated, the sum for a particular round should be `NULL` if that contenstant doesn't have rows in that table for that round, and in all other cases, it should do a SUM of the winningamounts for that contestant for that round. So Mr Wang has rows for Round 2, but didn't win anything, so SUM should be `0` not `NULL` and the other's the conditions I've stated are accurate.

Comment: @Shiva The SQL Fiddle you linked to my answer matches the expected output. That being said, the result would be NULL if they participated in a round and received a score of 0. Do you only want NULL results when a contestant didn't participate in a Match?

Comment: I missed the 0 for Mr. Wang in Round 2. @DhruvJoshi's solution captured it perfectly as long as there are only 3 rounds in a game (or a fixed amount of rounds).